# RuntimeIdentifier is required for native compilation. Try running dotnet publish with the -r option value specified. Error in .NET 8

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When trying to publish a new project in .NET 8 I get the error:

> Error : RuntimeIdentifier is required for native compilation. Try running dotnet publish with the -r option value specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause was because the default template for creating a ASP.NET Core Web API (native AOT) uses CreateSlimBuilder in the Program.cs file.  This is made for AOT and has no support for IIS (which I need), so I switched back to the old CreateBuilder

Comment: Is there any chance that you have used the `ASP.NET Core Web API (native AOT)` template when you were creating the app? Also you can just delete this setting.

Comment: @GuruStron that is exactly what I did come to find out, so I edited the answer to make it more clear.